# How do I do total time for multiple logs in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do a punch log using Google sheets and forms. The total time isn't working.

Was using

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"EMAIL",G2:G1048)
```

I want it to add all the G values if it came from a certain email for my team.
Would I need another sheet?

Comment: the sum_range and criteria_range arrays must have the same size.